# How to properly combine List[M[List[A]]] into M[List[A]] if M is a monad?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads, applicative, scala-cats

I have monads that wrap lists. I would like to combine these monads to form a monad that wraps the concatenation of all the lists.

```
M[List[A]] + M[List[A]] ==> M[List[A]]
```

To achieve this I did the following **(pseudo-code)**:

```
(1 to 10).foldLeft(Option(List(0)))((accumulator, i) => {
  for {
    prev <- accumulator
    more <- Option(List(i))
  } yield prev ++ more
})
```

This seems to compile but I kinda feel it should be simpler and **shorter** than this. Any ideas for improvement?

Comment: How many lists do you want to combine? Your example looks as if it's just `Monad[M].unit((1 to 10))`, so I don't understand what you want to combine there at all.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are asking. I want to combine 11 lists.

Comment: I'm asking whether you want to combine `(M[List[A]], M[List[A]])` or `List[M[List[A]]]` into `M[List[A]]`. Your first code snippet suggests that you want to combine pair of monads (`map2`), the second snippet suggests that you want to combine a sequence of monads of lists (`sequence` + `map`). Which one is it?

Comment: What's the difference? The natural transformation is the same.

Comment: The difference is that `(M[List[A]], M[List[A]])` can be transformed into `M[List[A]]` for any monad, whereas a more general `Foo[M[List[A]]]` can be transformed into `M[List[A]]` only if `Foo` is traversable. The fact that `M` is a monad does not automatically guarantee that you can swap arbitrary `Foo[M[...]]` into an `M[Foo[...]]`, and it is also not true that any `Foo[List[A]]` can be folded into `List[A]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an instance of `Traverse[List]`.
Every `Monad[M]` is a special case of `Applicative[M]`. Therefore, if you have a

```
List[M[List[A]]]
```

you should be able to use `sequence` in `Traverse[List]` with the `Applicative[M]` to first transform it into

```
M[List[List[A]]]
```

and then use `map` from `Functor[M]` to `flatten` it into

```
M[List[A]]
```

Something like

```
val lists: List[Option[List[A]]] = ???
val optLists: Option[List[List[A]]] = Traverse[List].sequence(lists)
val optList: Option[List[A]] = optLists.map(_.flatten)
```

in the case of `Option`.

Comment: Using postfix actually is a good thing when you don't want to rely on implicit resolution!

Answer (score 0):

I think semigroup (or SemigroupK) might be an abstraction you are looking for

Comment: Yes, but how :(

Comment: you can get what you want with something like this

https://gist.github.com/mibon/98e8a4c6437177b51be47cbae48e0719